# Start X on server via SSH

Tags: ssh, arch-linux, xorg

I have an `Arch Linux` system which does not start X on boot. I want to initiate `Xorg` on the server itself and do not want `X over SSH`

Comment: If X11 and any display manager is installed, you can try to start the display manager (like `lightdm`) - see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/display_manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the way to do this is the command 'startx'

You may wish to make SSH not allocate a TTY so you can exit the SSH session

Something like

```
ssh  -nqxT hostname "startx -- vt7 < /dev/null > /path/to/logfile.log 2>&1"
```

You may run into trouble with your user not being allowed to start the display unless they are logged into a console, and will likely need to configure the system in other ways to allow that, possibly in the 'pam' configuration, or possibly /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config